# Dynamically Restrict What CPU's a new process runs

Tags: linux, centos, rhel6

So, I've looked briefly at cgroups and numactl, but neither appears, based on the information i have found, to be quite what I need.

We use a piece of software, "fast-X", For our users to login to their graphical sessions over the network. it seems to have a terrible flaw, of when it starts running on more than a 120 core system, performance falls apart. Problem is, our big number crunching machines are 240 core systems.

So I need to find a way that can dynamically say "oh, someone is starting a fastx process, limit it to these X cores", as numactl and cgroups appear to be reliant on you starting the process with them, or forcefully moving the process after it has started, those won't really work for me...

For those unfamiliar with fastx, which is probably many, its basically a remote-desktop/X11 client that saves a users session, and generally(on 120 core systems or less) has great performance. So a user would be connecting to the server through a windows application, that would then automatically start their session, which is why I need something on the server end that will automatically restrict it, rather than it being something that would have to be forcefully started.

Thus far I haven't found anything, any idea's would be appreciated.

Comment: There are a few solutions to this. Let me investigate.

Comment: Is a wrapper script using numactl not an option? I.e, rename fastx to fastx.bin and create a script fastx with `numactl --cpunodebind=0 fastx.bin "$@"` in it.

Comment: Lots of words, but hardly descriptive. From what you've given it's unclear what makes you think you can't just set CPU affinity to needed processes. http://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset

Comment: Also see: http://serverfault.com/questions/403714/is-it-possible-to-set-cpu-affinity-for-particular-user + http://serverfault.com/questions/226180/what-types-of-linux-server-applications-should-have-their-cpu-affinity-set

Comment: @MarkWagner Hmm, to be honest I hadn't thought of that. I'm not 100% sure that the way fastx Runs it would allow, that but its worth experimenting with. Will try it tomorrow when i get into work.

-poige The way Fast-X runs it spawns a new instance of itself everytime a user connects. I could be entirely wrong in this, but all my initial tests with things like taskset, or numactl, looks like I can set the affinity for existing process', but new processes would have to be manually moved over as they were created. That being said, tomorrow I'll read what you've suggested.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would limiting fast-x to only run on some of the cores, fix the performance problem?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen TBH it might not. it runs perfectly on these systems if i go into the bios and disable cores. When looking at HTOP while in a fastX session, moving a window lights up every core like a christmas tree, so my belief is the way they are handling their multi-core execution is fiddly and has issues. So the hope is that limiting it will create the same performance gain as actually disabling cores does. May not work though, but its all i have right now.

Comment: @MarkWagner Hey, thanks for your idea, setting it up as a wrapper totally did what I was looking to accomplish. It sadly didn't solve the performance problem, but it *did* accomplish what I was trying to do, and gave me a new tool in my arsenal, so thanks. If you want to post it up as an answer, I'll gladly mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Most cluster schedulers/resource managers also allow binding of a task to specific CPUs or cores.  [Slurm](http://slurm.schedmd.com/documentation.html) and [Moab](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/8-1-1/basic/MWM/help.htm#topics/moabWorkloadManager/topics/intro/MWMwelcome.htm%3FTocPath%3D_____1) are resource managers that are very commonly used on HPC cluster systems and offer this functionality with standard CPUs as well as additional compute resources like GPUs, coprocessors and other compute accelerators.

If it is possible to keep the queue small enough theoretically a users login could automatically submit an interactive job to the queue then launch the results as the users login console in fastx.  It would even be possible to setup a mechanism which restricts users to certain groups of CPUs to ensure that no single user is allowed too many resources.  However if the queue grows too large users would have to wait for resources to become available.

While I have not actually seen a resource manager used in this manner it should be theoretically possible if the resource manager/scheduler allows for interactive jobs to be launched, which is a feature most modern schedulers have.  If nothing else will work this is an option that theoretically would work.  If the number of cores used by any specific process needs to be able to vary over the life of the process there may be other alternatives that are more suitable.

While not exactly similar there is an example of scheduling [Fastx on the Biowulf cluster at the NIH](http://biowulf.nih.gov/apps/fastxtoolkit.html).  They seem to use a PBS batch script to launch the jobs through a scheduler, so some of the concepts may be reusable.

[This example from Cornell](http://cbsu.tc.cornell.edu/ngw2010/Day1_exercise1.pdf) also seems to show a usage a Fastx with PBS so it seems like something that has been done before.  Though that example is admittedly a bit dated.

Comment: Hmm... This seems promising. Thank you for the information, I'll research this when I get in tomorrow.